# Is I-POMDP (Interactive POMDP) NEXP-complete?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, mdp

I know that the Dec-POMDP (Decentralized-POMDP) is NEXP-complete for finite time steps, but I wanted to know whether the I-POMDP is also NEXP-complete or not! If not, then what's the complexity of I-POMDP? I did some research about it, but unfortunately couldn't get a proper answer. Thanks in advance.